# What is the best approach for unit testing/integration testing GXT code?

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, testing, gwt, gxt

I have been tasked to setup a continuous integration environment for a GXT 2.1.1 and GWT 2.0.1 environment.  Unfortunately I am new to AJAX and Web Services and have little idea how to setup unit tests in the browser environment.  Unit tests for the server backend I already have done, since I am a pro at that.  GXT is not quite pure GWT which provides some unit testing structure.  If anyone has a good starting point...

Answer (score 1):

I feel the article  [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html) is fairly elaborate, Have you gone through that ?

I am assuming you are planning to test only the Async's and Server side (RemoteServiceServlet) part, so I don't understand how gwt/gxt differ in that, all the rules that apply to GWT, will still apply to GXT testing as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is unit testing and I will recommend using JUnit .